# Generate Morse Code (or any audio) in .NET (C# or VB.NET) without 3rd party dependencies, and without needing to use an audio file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, audio

So what's the best way to play a simple generated morse code in .NET (WinForms), without needing any external files, and without any 3rd party libraries? I only want to use the CLR, with no needless dependencies. C# or VB.NET code is welcome. I'm multilingual. ;P

(I really don't care what audio is generated. A simple one-frequency tone is just fine.)

Comment: I would look into using `console.beep`, make a parser that takes '-' and '.'. that is just my 2 cents though

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I need to be able to make Morse Code with it. the Console.Beep adds a pause that cannot be controlled, so that pushes it out of the options.

Comment: and i need to specifically control precise timing of both on and off sounds, so i can speed up the Morse Code and slow it down. It *should* have volume control ability too, but that's not absolutely necessary. Console.Beep has no volume control. :((

Comment: Are you willing to use a 3rd party library if it is easy to use and deploy? NuGet built in to visual studio makes using 3rd party libraries very easy. If the problem you have is with extra DLL's you can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) to combine the DLLs in to the exe.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this not a good question? If someone has a truly legit reason for the downvote, please correct me and explain why this is a bad question. If not, will someone please upvote my question? Thanks.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, i quite appreciate that added info, Scott. Mostly, my reasoning is this should be simple! (My exclamatory remark is not against you, but against MS for their poor documentation on this issue.) One problem with DLL's is also that you don't know what others have in their libraries. Yes, i trust that most DLL's are legit. But at the company i work for, they avoid 3rd parties like the plague because they'd rather not have sound than add the security risk for an issue that is not near as important as guaranteed security by not using 3rd party DLL's.

Comment: In my case, i *can* use a DLL if i need to. But i will search high and low first before i add DLL's. But with the dependency code being combined into the same exe, i will look into that! Thanks! That might not be so bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found half the help online at other sites, and about half i figured out how to do myself. Here's an almost ideal solution to what i needed:
1: Create a MemoryStream,
2: Write bytes for a WAV file to the MemoryStream (which will never get saved to disk, but will be played as if it were from a WAV file),
3: Seek to the beginning of the MemoryStream,
4: Play the MemoryStream with `System.Media.SoundPlayer(memoryStream).Play()`.
That's it. The most difficult part of that is creating the WAV-formatted byte stream... unless you just copy the code from someone like me. :P
Here's a .NET method that will play the sound with no external DLL's or anything external to .NET:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static void PlayBeep(UInt16 frequency, int msDuration, UInt16 volume = 16383)
{
    var mStrm = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(mStrm);

    const double TAU = 2 * Math.PI;
    int formatChunkSize = 16;
    int headerSize = 8;
    short formatType = 1;
    short tracks = 1;
    int samplesPerSecond = 44100;
    short bitsPerSample = 16;
    short frameSize = (short)(tracks * ((bitsPerSample + 7) / 8));
    int bytesPerSecond = samplesPerSecond * frameSize;
    int waveSize = 4;
    int samples = (int)((decimal)samplesPerSecond * msDuration / 1000);
    int dataChunkSize = samples * frameSize;
    int fileSize = waveSize + headerSize + formatChunkSize + headerSize + dataChunkSize;
    // var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    writer.Write(0x46464952); // = encoding.GetBytes("RIFF")
    writer.Write(fileSize);
    writer.Write(0x45564157); // = encoding.GetBytes("WAVE")
    writer.Write(0x20746D66); // = encoding.GetBytes("fmt ")
    writer.Write(formatChunkSize);
    writer.Write(formatType);
    writer.Write(tracks);
    writer.Write(samplesPerSecond);
    writer.Write(bytesPerSecond);
    writer.Write(frameSize);
    writer.Write(bitsPerSample);
    writer.Write(0x61746164); // = encoding.GetBytes("data")
    writer.Write(dataChunkSize);
    {
        double theta = frequency * TAU / (double)samplesPerSecond;
        // 'volume' is UInt16 with range 0 thru Uint16.MaxValue ( = 65 535)
        // we need 'amp' to have the range of 0 thru Int16.MaxValue ( = 32 767)
        double amp = volume >> 2; // so we simply set amp = volume / 2
        for (int step = 0; step < samples; step++)
        {
            short s = (short)(amp * Math.Sin(theta * (double)step));
            writer.Write(s);
        }
    }

    mStrm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    new System.Media.SoundPlayer(mStrm).Play();
    writer.Close();
    mStrm.Close();
} // public static void PlayBeep(UInt16 frequency, int msDuration, UInt16 volume = 16383)
```

Happy coding!
-Humilulo<><

Comment: The only non-ideal aspect of this solution as compared to what i was ideally looking for is that this is slightly more complicated that i had wanted. But the *very* nice thing with this is this allows *any* audio samples to be created. It is not limited to one volume, or even 16 channels of sound. The downer is the program must compute every sound sample one at a time. But i still like this very, very much.

Answer (score 2):

There're so many ways to achieve what you want..

I think the easiest for you would be playing some MIDI notes.

See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336028.aspx

NAudio library is open source, if you're really unhappy 'bout the extra DLL you could copy-paste relevant classes into your project.

Comment: Thanks, @Soonts. I will look into this too. An open source solution is nice too because a person can dig in and implement the code directly into one's project if need be. Open source is great! Thanks to all who share their code!

Comment: Thanks, Soonts. This is a place to find what i want. Unfortunately, it looks deep, but i up-voted you because it really does answer my question, and since it uses open source software, a person should be able to dig into NAudio source code if he/she doesn't want 3rd party dependencies and security risks. Thanks for a real answer. I will still look for a simpler solution. But I thank you for your legit answer! :)

Comment: AFAIK for MIDI, NAudio is merely a thin wrapper over the unmanaged API implemented in Winmm.dll, which is part of Windows (since Windows 2000). I wouldn't worry too much about the 3-rd party dependency in this case..

Answer (score 0):

Use [Console.Beep(frequency, duration)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1.aspx)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int freq = 500;
    int duration = 500;

    Console.Beep(freq, duration); //S
    Console.Beep(freq, duration);
    Console.Beep(freq, duration);

    Console.Beep(freq, duration * 2); //O
    Console.Beep(freq, duration * 2);
    Console.Beep(freq, duration * 2);

    Console.Beep(freq, duration); //S
    Console.Beep(freq, duration);
    Console.Beep(freq, duration);

}
```

Comment: Console.Beep does not work. Please see my comments under the question for reasons why.

Comment: make the frequency super high or super low you won't hear anything.

Comment: @SamFisher83, if you read my comments you would understand why your Console.Beep will not work for me. I was not aware of RobertSnyder's extra info on problems with it on WinXP.

Comment: @Scott it does work at least on windows 7 why didn't you actually try it?

Comment: @Shawn you could have used two different frequencies and varied the lengths specifically.

Comment: They have changed the behavior seance I last tested it, I edited your question as I could not remove my downvote without a edit being performed.

Comment: @SamFisher83, Console.Beep *does not work* for Morse Code. i commented in the comments, and i quote "i need to specifically control precise timing of both on and off sounds, so i can speed up the Morse Code and slow it down." Console.Beep does not provide this functionality. If you still think it works, then please tell me at what WPM (Word per minute) rate your beeps are beeping Morse Code. And when you speed it up, the sucky timing of the Console.Beep will be worse because that off delay cannot be controlled. How many times must i repeat that Console.Beep does not work?

Comment: Console.Beep works for what sounds *like* Morse Code, and it *resembles* Morse Code. But it is not *real* Morse Code. when generating real Morse Code, you need to be able to control the speed of the on and off 'beeps'. Console.Beep only gives you control of the on 'beeps', not the off delay. Yes you can *add* more delay, but you cannot control it to have less delay that it gives by default, can you? Console.Beep does *not* work. Oh, did i forget to mention that Console.Beep is unsuitable for Morse Code use? Please excuse my lack of sharing that it doesn't work.

Comment: the timing of the code, as it is now, is not correct Morse Code timing. the pause between dots and dashes in the same letter should be the same time period as the dot itself. the time period for the dash should be 3 times the time period for the dot. that code only doubles the time period, showing that the coder does not know the basic specifics of Morse Code. but this dash delay can b achieved with Console.Beep. But the off delay cannot correctly b achieved @ speeds faster than the mandatory silence between Console.Beep tones. no dual frequency trick can solve that. Console.Beep doesn't work.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the extra attempt to show what Console.Beep can do tho. Unfortunately that delay between beeps is quite a delay. So the speed above is about as fast of Morse Code as can be produced with it. My purpose is to learn Morse Code at a fast speed and practice Morse Code at increasing speeds, thus i need real Morse Code rather than child's play that resembles Morse Code. But thanks for some demo code, Scott.